# Bash script to run chmod and skip wile with badstr

Tags: bash, scripting, chmod

I apologize for my question but I am a beginner and I am starting to code and learn and I have no clue what am I doing but still I am learning. I took community course and struggled with my homework. 2 of the 3 assignments I've done and I'm struggling with no 3.

Assignment is:

"write BASH script to run CHMOD 644 command on file /folder/file1, /folder/file2 up to file /folder/file28 and skip all files containing string badstr. I have no clue how to do it, I am searching and reading all morning and still didn't figure it out. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go step by step:

1. Create a loop over the files (which means that you have to generate that list of files) -> for
2. Check if every file being processed contains the forbidden string -> grep
3. Perform the chmod if the file passes the test -> if, test, chmod

Answer (score 0):

So based on your answer i got this now. Hopefully i am on right track

```
 #!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  cat $f
while read -r str
do
   echo "$str"
   grep "$str" /path/to/other/files
done < inputfile
chmod g+w `cat inputfile
```